# Get a row from a dataframe to insert on another dataframe in a loop

Tags: python, pandas, loops, insert, row

I'm trying to get a row from a dataframe in a loop to insert it on another empty dataframe.
The goal of it is to fill step by step the empty dataframe to convert it to an excel file.

Thank you for your help.

```
dt_agregat = pd.DataFrame(columns=["a","b","c","d"])

for sir in list_siret:
    str_siret = str(sir)
    list_sirets.append(str_siret)
print(list_sirets)

for sirets in list_sirets:
    
    try:
        
        r = requests.get('https://myAPI'+sirets, headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'})
        data = r.json()
    except urllib.error.URLError:
        list_sirets_error.append(sirets)
        continue
        
    str_datajs = json.dumps(data, indent=4)
    a_json = json.loads(str_datajs)
    del a_json["header"]
    
    df_a_json = pd.DataFrame(a_json)

    final_data = pd.json_normalize(a_json,record_path=["Sublime"], errors='ignore',record_prefix='_')
    dt = pd.DataFrame(final_data)

    dt_agregat.append(dt.iloc[0])
```

Comment: No i didn't but i found a solution. In my code this line works perfectly well. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

well i tried this and its seems to works :

dt_agregat = dt_agregat.append(dt,True)